# ODBC Item on MySQL query causes Zabbix server to stop

Tags: mysql, zabbix, odbc

I'am new to Zabbix. Today I've tried to add a SQL item (Database monitoring) to a host without success.

Without this SQL item, the Zabbix server runs fine. I check this with `service zabbix-server status`.

After I enable the SQL item, hit *Check now* for it, and run `service zabbix-server status` again, I've got an error:

```
 zabbix-server.service - Zabbix Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-09 15:41:10 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 330 ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 335 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_server -c $CONFFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  ...
```

You can see that process 330 reports **status=1/FAILURE**.

After I hit *Check now* the Zabbix frontend pops up with *Request sent successfully*. But looking for this item in Monitoring > Latest data there is no value.

The item is configured as:

- Type: Database monitor
- Key: db.odbc.select[num-of-events,backend]
- User name: (empty)
- Password: (empty)
- SQL query: `select 1;`
- Type of information: Numeric (unsigned)

The ODBC data source *backend* seems to be working fine:

```
$ isql backend
> +---------------------------------------+
> | Connected!                            |
> |                                       |
> | sql-statement                         |
> | help [tablename]                      |
> | quit                                  |
> |                                       |
> +---------------------------------------+
>  SQL> select 1;
> +---------------------+
> | 1                   |
> +---------------------+
> | 1                   |
> +---------------------+
> SQLRowCount returns 1
> 1 rows fetched
```

Here is my ODBC config:

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[mysql]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8S.so
FileUsage = 1
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
backend  = MySQL unicode backend DSN

[backend]
Driver = mysql
Decription = Connector/ODBC Driver to Backend DB
Server = localhost
Port = 3306
User = ???
Password = ???
Database = backend
OPTION = 3
SOCKET = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Zabbix is running on Debian Stretch.
Zabbix server version is 4.0.1.
MySQL version is 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Any idea why the server crashes?

**Edit**: There is no difference when using the ANSI driver libmyodbc8a.so instead of the Unicode driver libmyodbc8w.so.

**Edit 2**: Tested also with ANSI and Unicode version mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.11-linux-debian9-x86-64bit without success.

**zabbix-server.log** tells the error

```
 10002:20181109:170635.268 Got signal [signal:11(SIGSEGV),reason:1,refaddr:0x60]. Crashing ...
 10002:20181109:170635.269 ====== Fatal information: ======
 ...
 10002:20181109:170635.269 === Backtrace: ===
 10002:20181109:170635.270 27: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](zbx_backtrace+0x35) [0x55a008633b24]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 26: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](zbx_log_fatal_info+0x119) [0x55a008633d38]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 25: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](+0xf0060) [0x55a008634060]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 24: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x110c0) [0x7f1e2039a0c0]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 23: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(+0x79e4d) [0x7f1e12b3ee4d]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 22: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(_Z22add_compiled_collationP12CHARSET_INFO+0x25) [0x7f1e12b3f995]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 21: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(_Z22init_compiled_charsetsi+0x15) [0x7f1e12b8eda5]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 20: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(+0x7918f) [0x7f1e12b3e18f]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xe739) [0x7f1e20397739]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(_ZSt9call_onceIRFvvEJEEvRSt9once_flagOT_DpOT0_+0x5a) [0x7f1e12b3dcea]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 17: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(_Z22my_charset_get_by_nameP17MY_CHARSET_LOADERPKcji+0x2a) [0x7f1e12b3e67a]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 16: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(_Z21get_charset_by_csnamePKcji+0x3b) [0x7f1e12b3e70b]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 15: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(myodbc_init+0x156) [0x7f1e12b24951]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 14: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(my_SQLAllocEnv+0x1c) [0x7f1e12b2825b]
 10002:20181109:170635.270 13: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so(SQLAllocHandle+0x60) [0x7f1e12b29326]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 12: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2(+0xdbb7) [0x7f1e1f43dbb7]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2(SQLConnect+0x217) [0x7f1e1f43fdc7]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 10: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](zbx_odbc_connect+0x1ac) [0x55a0085c697b]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 9: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](get_value_db+0x22a) [0x55a00859d132]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 8: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](+0x4968d) [0x55a00858d68d]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 7: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](+0x4b950) [0x55a00858f950]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 6: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](poller_thread+0x192) [0x55a0085909d4]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 5: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](zbx_thread_start+0x32) [0x55a0086411de]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 4: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](MAIN_ZABBIX_ENTRY+0x9ac) [0x55a00857bcee]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 3: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](daemon_start+0x315) [0x55a008633346]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 2: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](main+0x2f6) [0x55a00857b340]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7f1e1d1de2e1]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 0: /usr/sbin/zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 1 values in 0.004743 sec, getting values](_start+0x2a) [0x55a00857a51a]
 10002:20181109:170635.271 === Memory map: ===
 ...
```

**Edit 3**: Tested with mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.13-linux-debian6.0-x86-64bit.tar.gz and no success.
This failure seems related to https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7665 and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by using MariaDB ODBC connector instead of the MySQL connector.

1. Download https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.0.6/ I use debian-x86_64.tar.gz
2. Unpack it `tar -xvzf mariadb-connector-odbc-3.0.6-ga-debian-x86_64.tar.gz`
3. Copy `cp lib/libmaodbc.so /usr/lib/`
4. Add the following lines to **/etc/odbcinst.ini**

   ```
   [mariadb]
   Description = ODBC for MariaDB
   Driver = /usr/lib/libmaodbc.so
   ```
5. Edit you DNS in **/etc/odbc.ini**

   ```
   Driver = mariadb
   Socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   ```

   The last line is also important, otherwise the connector looks for /tmp/mysqld.sock.

This works on Debian Jessie (8) but not with Debian Stretch (9). If you run `ldd libmaodbc.so` you see that the MariaDB ODBC connector depends on libssl.so.1.0.0 but Stretch have only libssl.so.1.0.2 and libssl.so.1.1 installed.